# Trying to deploy ec2 instance with Apache libcloud outside of default VPC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My organization creates our own VPC's and does not leverage the default one provided by AWS.  I am trying to use apache libcloud to deploy instances within non-default VPC's.  However, libcloud complains that no VPC Id was specified.  I can't seem to find where you are supposed to specify this parameter.  I looked in the code, asked on IRC, and combed through the documentation.  I tried providing a "location" parameter using an AZ but that doesn't seemto take either.  Has anyone come across this or dealt with it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like you have to specify the subnet id you want to deploy the instance to if you do not have a default VPC.

Here is my example for anyone else that needs assistance with this.

```
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver
from libcloud.compute.base import NodeImage
import os

ACCESS_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AMI_ID = os.getenv('AMI_ID')
SIZE_ID = os.getenv('SIZE_ID', 't2.micro')
REGION = os.getenv('REGION','us-east1')
KEYNAME = os.getenv('KEYNAME')
SUBNET = os.getenv('SUBNET')

cls = get_driver(Provider.EC2)

driver = cls(ACCESS_ID, SECRET_KEY, region=REGION)

subnet = [ s for s in driver.ex_list_subnets() if s.id == SUBNET][0]
size = [ s for s in driver.list_sizes() if s.id == SIZE_ID][0]
image = NodeImage(id=AMI_ID, name=None, driver=driver)

node = driver.create_node(name='group-test', image=image, size=size, ex_subnet=subnet, ex_keyname=keyname)
```